# gstreamer WebM live Streaming, How to reduce Delay?

Tags: gstreamer, live-streaming, webm

**UPDATED**:
I am using below pipeline for video streaming from camera using webm live Streaming,

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=320,height=240 ! vp8enc end-usage=cbr cpu-used=5 threads=4 target-bitrate=2048 max-quantizer=40 min-quantizer=10 cq-level=10 ! webmmux streamable=true !  shout2send ip=192.168.1.139 port=8000 password=uurmi321 mount=/test.webm max-bitrate=2048
```

While viewing that video from firefox,

http://IP:8000/test.webm

By adding some properties at vp8enc then delay is reduced to 6 to 8 sec.

But, i need reduce up to 1 to 2 seconds.

What more properties i need to set?

Comment: I would first analyse what is introducing the delay.. what about using `... ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink` and check with vlc player the output.. analyse the delay with that.. if its still too long, than check some vp8enc parameters, if its not than the icecast server is at blame(if I understand shout2cast correctly)..

Comment: but i would like to play that stream in the web browser, so i have used the shout2send element.

Comment: ok nice :) I dont know which properties.. maybe ask on IRC, but also try my suggestion which will show you how much icecast server adds (this may be those 6 seconds ;)

Comment: may i know how check the icecast server?

Comment: as I said already make a pipe with vp8enc rtpvp8pay and udpsink and play on vlc, measure time.. if its under 6 secs than logicaly the icecase server is the additional time.. its simple comparison test, eliminating the shout2send and icecast from the chain.. otherwise I dont know how to measure the icecast server delay more directly..